# Apple denied my app because it crashed on app launch... but i cant mimic this

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, crash-reports

The document they sent me contains this.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010033c0e0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [7433]
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Thread 0 is my Main app, im guessing my delegate?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID:Constants.MAIN_AD_MOB)

        let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]

        // Replace 'YOUR_APP_ID' with your OneSignal App ID.
        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                        appId: Constants.ONE_SIGNAL_ID,
                                        handleNotificationAction: nil,
                                        settings:onesignalInitSettings)

        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;

        // Recommend moving the below line to prompt for push after informing the user about
        //   how your app will use them.
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
            print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
        })

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if (!preferences.bool(forKey: "userVisited")) {
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstTimeUser") as! UIPageViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
        }



        return true
    }
```

I can't figure out what caused this... any help would be great.

Comment: Did they not provide stack trace?

Comment: they did, they are all very long, but nothing in there refers to a crash. Theres a huge list of threads, and then binary images. when debugging in xcode, i get to see the error and the line.

Comment: Usually the thread that was the source of the crash bears some designation of such at the top of its stack trace. (And your message here says that it was triggered by thread 0, which you are correct is the main thread, so I’d start there. But it’s not necessarily the app delegate.) So I would take a long hard look at that stack trace for that thread (ideally symbolicating it, if you can). These stack traces can be hard to read, but are designed to show you where it crashed, so you can diagnose it. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: You're using Firebase but not Crashlytics?  Why not?  You could configure Crashlytics first, and then send Crashlytics some log messages at each step of the rest of your app launch, so that when Apple next crashes your app, you'd have a log of how far they got (along with a great stack trace).

Comment: @Rob i followed the instruction to take their .txt file but it didnt do anything, still the same log

Comment: @Smartcat im giong to implement this now.

Comment: @Smartcat wow, where has this been all my life!!! i love it. looking forward to putting it to use....then again, who wants crashes!

Comment: @soldfor if you'd like to chat about it, you can find me on iOS Developers slack. I can explain some further strategies.

Comment: @Smartcat How to get an invite to the iOSDevelopper Slack?

Comment: [iOS Developers HQ](https://ios-developers.io)